# 404 страница битрикс

Tags: php, битрикс, error404

Возник следующий вопрос. Когда в настройках компонента news.list указывается ссылка на 404 страницу, то где хранится это информация о ссылке, потому что в коде почему-то не показывается где путь к 404 странице, но если страница не существует, происходит переход на 404 страницу, которую я указал, а мне нужно временно настроить переход на стандартную в битриксе 404 страницу. Поэтому не могу найти, где мне нужно стереть этот путь

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проверьте в настройках компонента параметр `FILE_404`, если верить [документации](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/user_help/components/content/articles_and_news/news_list.php) путь к специальной странице хранится именно в нем. Этот параметр становится активным при `SHOW_404 => "Y"`